# Alternatives to the Vincenty geodesic functions in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: openlayers, geodesic

I'm migrating an application from OpenLayers 2 which uses OpenLayers.Util.destinationVincenty() to compute the projected latitude and longitude of a point from an origin given an angle and distance in metres.

destinationVincenty() and the other related geodesic utility functions are absent in OpenLayers 3.  I guess that they have been replaced by some other facility, but I'm struggling to find anything that helps.  I can't believe that I will have to re-code the Vincenty logic in my application, so...

Does anyone know of an embedded OL3 solution for geodesic arithmetic?

Answer (score 1):

Some things are already in the library but at the moment, when the generated library is bundled, it does not export Vincenty methods.
If you make your custom OpenLayers 3 build, you can change this behaviour.

You should also ask on the official OpenLayers 3 list at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ol3-dev and take a look at [those issues](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/search?q=vincenty&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93) on the Github OpenLayers 3 repository.

Answer (score 1):

Old post, but came across it looking for drawing geodesic ellipsoids in OL3. If you just want to add it without creating a custom build, take a look at ellipsoid.js in the OL3 distro (ol\ol\ellipsoid). The vincenty methods appear to be in there without the greek symbols.